# firebug reporting reference to undefined... jquery.cache [id] [name]

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I am trying to learn javascript/jquery, using firebug to debug and have built a page, which I have reduced to a minimal below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" "text/javascript">

function geoAddress() {
    alert("start");
    var postcode = $("#PostCode").val();

    }
</script>
<title>Postcode</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<h2>Create</h2>

<form action="/Venues/Create" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label for="PostCode">Postcode:</label>
                <input id="PostCode" name="PostCode" type="text" value="" />
                <input type="button" onclick="geoAddress();"/>      
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe that this worked previously, but now although it does work (i.e. I press the button and get an alert) in firebug, on first loading I see a [javascript error](http://img.skitch.com/20090701-cc99qyyajiynjmbacys39hdi26.jpg).

I have jquery-1.3.2.js loaded in the same directory as my file.

I seem to be struggling with firebug so would appreciate pointing in the direction of tutorials for the current version for javascript debugging. I can't even see a way to view the whole error message.

I would appreciate any help with what this error is and also pointers in the right direction for using firebug.

Comment: The entire error message should appear in the 'console' tab.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought, but the console shows nothing. It is blank: http://img.skitch.com/20090701-ru1xj3c3d6cq7w4h5g2aa4gnwd.jpg

Comment: Select the down arrow next to console and ensure 'enabled' is checked.

Comment: Yes, I was getting reports in the console, just nothing that resembled the js error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step - Can you make sure jQuery is being requested successfully. In firebug click the Net tab and it will show you all requests that are made and the failed ones will appear in red.

Comment: OK, I had to enable the net tab, but after doing that (and restarting firefox too) I get nothing other than: http://img.skitch.com/20090701-x779jwe6g1q3yswpfw664nepq8.jpg.

Comment: try reloading the page (F5) whilst you have firebug & the net tab visible. It only shows requests made whilst it is enabled & visible

Comment: I get the same result. It flicks to the script tab when the error comes up. I do seem to get similar error for stackoverflow now though. I'll try on another machine tomorrow and report what happens there.

Comment: hmmm sounds like a reboot, try again, on fail remove & reinstall firebug, again try on fail remove & reinstall firefox

Comment: Think that had a problem with firefox or firebug or both, I've created a new profile and reinstalled firebug, and it all works fine now. Thanks for your help.